# Getting error when upload xlsx data to s3

Tags: javascript, node.js, sheetjs

I am trying to upload xlsx buffer to s3 but getting error cannot find file content_types .xml in zip

```
wbresult = XLSX.utils.book_new;
const wbo = {bookType: 'xlsx', type:'buffer'};
const wbr = XLSX.write(wbresult, wbo)
```

Comment: Please edit and add more details. More code, more context, etc. It is unanswerable at the moment

Comment: I want to upload xlsx to s3 . But I am getting error cannot find file content_types .xml in zip